# Why is my image not showing up in my ShadowRoot popup?

Tags: javascript, html, image, google-chrome-extension, shadow-dom

I'm making a Chrome extension called TL;DR, that displays a summarized version of each Google search link in a popup box to the side. I'm currently programming the popup box UI  which I made by attaching a shadowRoot element to the document. I'm trying to make a loading icon, but the image I want to use isn't showing up, and I think there is something incorrect/missing with the javascript.

Here is the HTML of the popup box, though the HTML doesn't seem to be the problem, since I pasted the same code into another program and the image dispayed properly.

```
var templateLoading = `<div id= "tl-dr-content" style="visibility:visible">
     <h1>Just a Moment...</h1>
     <h2> <img src="/images/loading-yellow.jpg"/>
</div>`
```

Here is the creation of the DOM element:

```
  var tldr = document.createElement("div");
  tldr.id = ("tl-dr-popup");
  var shadowRoot =  tldr.attachShadow({mode:'open'});
  shadowRoot.innerHTML = `
  <div id="tl-dr-wrapper" style="visibility:hidden"></div>
  `;
  document.body.appendChild(tldr);
```

Here is the javascript that displays the popup once the button is clicked:

```
var render = function(templateLoading, node) {
    if (!node) return;
    node.innerHTML = templateLoading;
};

render(templateLoading, document.querySelector('#tl-dr-popup').shadowRoot.querySelector('#tl-dr-wrapper'));
document.querySelector('#tl-dr-popup').shadowRoot.querySelector('#tl-dr-wrapper').style.visibility = "visible";
```

Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

Comment: If this is inside the content script you need to list the image in [web_accessible_resources](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/manifest/web_accessible_resources) and use chrome.runtime.getURL to specify the url or manually specify the full chrome-extension:// URL.

Comment: @wOxxOm thanks loads! Had no idea I was supposed to do this.